# Copying corresponding text in Selenium (python)

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, web

So I'm using Selenium with python 2.7. I'm pretty new with python and know less about webdev, so I apologize in advance if I use incorrect terms.

In the source of the page, this variable contains what I need...

```
var envConfig = {
    devMode: false,
    sessionTimeout: 14400,
    sessionTimeoutWarningEnabled: true,
    user: 'abc123@gmail.com'
}
```

Using selenium, is there any way that I would be able to copy the variable associated with "user"?

Comment: You want to extract this data from page source into your python code using selenium?

Comment: Selenium is rarely used to extract (parts of) the source code of a web page. Consider using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for that. Also, it would help your question if you could provide either the link to that page (so that we may see the source code ourselves) OR add a larger extract from the source code.